# Default options for external commands in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to make `grep` case insensitive by applying a default option `-i` to `grep`. The standard way in PowerShell is to use a function:

```
function grep {
    env grep -i $args
}
```

`Grep` also accepts text to search via standard input (`cat file | grep search`).

A simple way to achieve that is:

```
function grep($search) {
    $input | env grep -i $search
```

Can I combine these two so that function `grep` knows it was called in a pipeline? Or is there an even simpler way?

Comment: Change the function body from `env grep -i $args` to `$input |env grep -i`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen with your solution, the first usage (`grep $search $file`) does not work anymore.

Comment: `$input` is an automatic variable. Do not define it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `env grep` means that you have a Unix*-ish* environment with a `grep.exe` somewhere. The proper way of wrappting that in a function that can handle parameter *and* pipeline input looks somewhat like this:

```
function grep {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='content')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Search,

        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName='content',
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [string]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName='file',
            Position=1,
            Mandatory=$true
        )]
        [string[]]$File
    )

    Begin {
        $grep = & env grep
    }

    Process {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'file') {
            & $grep -i $Search $File
        } else {
            $InputObject | & $grep -i $Search
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not work and it cannot work. Grep uses two different syntaxes: search, file name and the content of file name coming via standard input. In your solution, text coming via standard input would be interpreted as a file name.

Comment: @user245396 Sorry, misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. This might only work interactively and not in a script - because of `$input` - but aliasing is generally considered an interactive technique (although providing standard options to commands not necessarily).

In this example I'm using `ag` - the Silver Searcher - as it's case insensitive (actually "case-smart"), recursive and enables color by default. It searches the current directory if no path is given (which is the first "test case" to show that the function is working as intended)

```
function ag {
    if ($input.Count) {
        $input.Reset()
        $input | env ag -i $args
    }
    else {
        env ag --depth -1 --hidden --skip-vcs-ignores $args
    }
}
```

[image]